# Refresh Existing Grid (PartialView) with New Data on Ajax Call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a PartialView which renders a Grid using a List of Model Class passed from the controller.

```
@model IEnumerable<DeliveryDashboard.Models.UpcomingDMR>

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_DMRGrid.cshtml", Model)
```

The Grid Renders perfectly. Now I have added a Drop down at the top of the Grid.

in the `OnChange` event of the Drop down, I need to hit the controller and get an Updated list of Same Model Class which should refresh the existing Grid.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    //Refresh Grid on Date Range Change
    $('#DateRange').change(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/DMR/UpcomingDMRByDateRange/")',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ DateRange: $('#DateRange option:selected').val() }),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
                // Refresh partialView Here
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My controller code returns the List of Model Class which I need to use to bind the Partial View.

```
public List<UpcomingDMR> UpcomingDMRByDateRange(string DateRange)
{
    // get data from database and prepare List<UpcomingDMR> 
    return NewDataList;
}
```

Now How can I refresh my partial View from the `Success block` of my Ajax Call ?

Comment: Please provide feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this in your success method :

```
$(function () {
//Refresh Grid on Date Range Change
$('#DateRange').change(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Content("~/DMR/UpcomingDMRByDateRange/")',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ DateRange: $('#DateRange option:selected').val() }),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {
            $("#your_partial_view_id").load('@Url.Action("Foo","Bar")',result)
        }
    });
  });
});
```